# Selecting from search result list with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I know there are similar questions but I couldn't manage to utilize the solutions. That's why I am asking for my specific problem.

My code looks like:

```
 driver.get("https://")
    driver.maximize_window()
    login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_xpath).send_keys(email)
    login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(pwd_xpath).send_keys(pwd)
    login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(continue_xpath)
    login.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    
    ticker = 'DB:0NU'
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_xpath))).send_keys(ticker)
    
    time.sleep(10)
    
    print(search)
    
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='popup-portal']/div/div/div/div/ul")
    for element in elements:
        print(element.text)
        try:
            if element.text == ticker:
                element.click()
        except:
            pass
```

I don't get any error results, but nethertheless, the solution is not satisfying, because my code doesn't select 'DB:0NU' from the search result, even though one can see it in the search result. How can I make my code click the element?

A sample of the html source code:

```
<ul data-cy-id="search-results-list" class="sc-gCwZxT kelPjw"><li>
```

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some issues with the locators on the page, the ones that get the search results.

Besides this, in the `for` loop you need a `break` when the desired value is found because you don't want to continue searching for other results once you found it.

```
    driver.get("https://simplywall.st/dashboard")
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="username"]'))).send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="password"]').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-cy-id="button-submit-login"]').click()

    ticker = 'DB:0NU'
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="search-search-field"]'))).send_keys(ticker)

    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-cy-id="search-results-list"] p')))

    for element in elements:
        print(element.text)
        try:
            if element.text == ticker:
                element.click()
                company = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-cy-id="company-header-title"]'))).text
                print(company)
                break
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Ty for your support, unfortunately clicking the element and switching to the next page still doesn't function.

Comment: @Numpy Fixed it now. `print(company)` is now printing Nutanix from the redirected page

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting following error:
File "D:\... <module>
    elements = WebDriverWait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-cy-id="search-results-list"] p')))
TypeError: until() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'

Unfortunately element.click does not redirect to the next page.

Comment: That's because you didn't used `wait` variable but `WebDriverWait`. `WebDriverWait` is a class and needs to be instantiated, as a I did above with  `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`